# Pre-requisite Check on Uninstall

Tags: wix

I am using the below code to check one of my pre-requisite.

```
<Property Id="PRE_INSTALLATION">
<RegistrySearch Id="RegistrySearch" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Name="Current Resource" Key="SOFTWARE\ABC\BCD"/>
</Property>
<Condition Message="[ProductName] requires ABC.">PRE_INSTALLATION</Condition>
```

The problem is that this gets executed even on un-install. How do I disable this condition check during un-install.

Answer (score 3):

Solved..

It is just that I have to use

```
<Condition Message="[ProductName] requires ABC."><![CDATA[Installed OR PRE_INSTALLATION]]>
```

Have a great day.

Bye.